# Cannot resolve symbol FragmentPaperAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio

Ok...

I've got an issue I don't quite understand.
I've created an application for the past week, and decided do make some changes. So I started again from scratch. So I create my main activity, I feel it, I create a second activity which is supposed to contain tabs (I just add the add activity feature of Android Studio) and now I get errors like this:

`Cannot resolve symbol FragmentPagerAdapter`
on line: `import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;`

or `Cannot resolve symbol ViewPager`
on `import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;`

The project builds all right, and run on my phone, but I have all these errors which is really annoying and not helpful. I read somewhere that the `Android Support Library` should be installed, it is if I trust the SDK manager. And it's really weird since it's working in the other project.

What should I do?

Thanks

[EDIT] typo
[EDIT2] Tried to restart the IDE, clean caches and clean/rebuild the project. Nothing worked :/

Comment: FragmentPaperAdapter or FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: Since it builds and runs properly, it should be an IDE issue. First try doing a clean build , then an "invalidate cache and reset", if that also doesn't work, then close and reopen IDE. Those are three basic things to do before panicking.:D

Comment: I already cleaned the project and restarted the IDE several times :-) I did not know about the invalidate thing, but it works! Thanks :-)

Spoke too soon... still nothing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I finally solved it. I named my application with a `!` at the end. Which means that when creating the project, the root folder got a `!` in it, which apparently broke the IDE.

I created a new project, kept the app name but removed the `!` from the folder's name, and it works again...